# ionic 3 native geolocation not working

Tags: javascript, ios, ionic3

All of a sudden my geolocation is not working and I tried ionic native geolocation 2,3, and 4 and its still giving me the same error:

```
ERROR: Method 'getLocation:' not defined in Plugin 'Geolocation'
```

This is the line which causes the above error:

```
this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(geoLocationOptions).then((position) => {
})
```

It was working originally and then all of a sudden it stopped not sure why all of a sudden it stopped working.  Any ideas guys?

Answer (score 0):

Ionic native geolocation is fined working

First thing is to install two, the cordova plugins and ionic native.

```
$ ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-geolocation --variable GEOLOCATION_USAGE_DESCRIPTION="Location Description here"
$ npm install --save @ionic-native/geolocation
```

Second is add the plugins app to your module provider in root folder of default ionic app.

> src/app/app.module.ts

```
import { Geolocation } from '@ionic-native/geolocation';

@NgModule({
 ...

 providers: [
  ...
  Geolocation
  ...
  ]
  ...
 })
 export class AppModule { }
```

Third and last thing is importing the plugins in the page, and add a contructor like this:

```
 constructor(private geolocation: Geolocation) {}
```

Then used the code you have.